# cmd.exe find files and directories with full path?

Tags: windows, cmd

I just noticed, that looking up files like this in Windows `cmd.exe`:

```
C:\test>dir . /s | findstr /E "test.exe"
24-05-2016  18:11           262.656 test.exe
24-05-2016  18:11           262.656 test.exe
```

... does not provide the full path to the files, because it is not in the output of `dir` to begin with. In Unix, I could do:

```
find /c/test -name "test.exe"
```

... and I would get a list of absolute paths. How can I do the same in Windows Command Prompt `cmd.exe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print full path use `dir` with `/b`

```
dir /S /b "test.exe"
```